# Trying to use the dates on the first column and have them separated into month, day and year in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Trying to use the dates on the first column and have them separated into Month, Day and Year in another column. The dates on the first column has random blank spaces in between and on the results column have the months, day and year removing those spaces.

I'm not sure what function to use. Any advice or help is much appreciated.

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you need to keep the spaces in column `A`?

Comment: Hi Cybernetic.nomad,  Yes Column A has spaces using it to reference something else in other columns,  Unless you mean removing it from extracting it from the original column?  Thanks for the help and any advice.

Comment: Are the dates in column A Excel dates or text dates?  BTW, if those are actually blank cells in between the dates (as opposed to other content), you might be able to simplify this by using a filter to hide the blank rows.  Then parse the date components.  Copy, unfilter, paste to consolidate them.

Comment: Hi fixer1234, that's an interesting way and then use the function of =month, =day, and =year to separate them into their own columns.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you need to keep them in the order presented. If you do, you can use the following:

```
C2: =IFERROR(MONTH(INDEX($A$1:$A$500,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$500<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$500),""),ROW()-1))),"")
D2: =IFERROR(DAY(INDEX($A$1:$A$500,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$500<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$500),""),ROW()-1))),"")
E2: =IFERROR(YEAR(INDEX($A$1:$A$500,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$500<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$500),""),ROW()-1))),"")
```

If your okay with a helper column you can just extract the dates into their own column with:

```
F2: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$500,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$500<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$500),""),ROW()-1)),"")
```

All of these are array formulas entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. This way you only have to do the lookup once per row instead of three times.

If they can be in any order you can skip the Index part and just use:

```
C2: =IFERROR(MONTH(SMALL($A$1:$A$500,ROW()-1)),"")
D2: =IFERROR(DAY(SMALL($A$1:$A$500,ROW()-1)),"")
E2: =IFERROR(YEAR(SMALL($A$1:$A$500,ROW()-1)),"")
```

Again, if you can use a helper column you can use:

```
F2: =IFERROR(SMALL($A$1:$A$500,ROW()-1),"")
```

These will give you results in ascending date order and *don't* have to be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Expand $A$1:$A$500 to whatever you need and copy the formulas down to expand how many results you want to see.

The first set of formulas generates a list of row numbers that have values, then uses the Small function to pull the nth value in ascending order, where n is one less than the row the formula is on (Row()-1).

The second set of formulas is exactly the same except instead of a list of row numbers it just pulls the list of dates directly.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but it's a lot for people to re-enter to verify that it works.  People often post solutions that look right, but contain a typo, or don't work for some cases, or otherwise have a problem.  This would be easier to upvote if you add a screenshot of the solution demonstrating that it works.  :-)

Comment: I had considered that, but found that my screenshot would have looked identical to the one in the question, or near enough.

Comment: ergo,..  That's kind of the concept of a verification, it should produce the same result.  :-)